# Get coordinates of country location using lookup_coords() function from rtweet package

Tags: r, twitter, google-geocoding-api, rtweet

I have installed rtweet and when I want to collect tweets from a specific country other than USA, the package doesn´t collect any data. I have already installed the **Geocoding API**, **Maps JavaScript API** and the **Geolocation API** with the same API key from Google as an environment variable in R. Here are the steps I followed:

generate a google maps_token

```
google_maps_token<-"my key XXXXXXXXXX"
```

path of home directory

```
home_directory <- path.expand("~/")
```

combine with name for token

```
file_name <- file.path(home_directory, "google_maps_token.rds")
```

save token to home directory

```
saveRDS(google_maps_token, file = file_name)
```

Create an environment variable

```
cat(paste0("GOOGLE_MAPS_PAT=", file_name),
file = file.path(home_directory, ".Renviron"),
append = TRUE)
```

Visualize API key envirnomental variables

```
usethis::edit_r_environ()
```

TWITTER_PAT=/Users/xxxxxx/.rtweet_token1.rds
GOOGLE_MAPS_PAT=/Users/xxxxxx//google_maps_token.rds

After saving the google api key, I restart RStudio to start collecting tweets and this happens:

load rtweet library

```
library(rtweet)
```

collect tweets from USA

```
tweets_USA <- search_tweets("#lang:en",
                        geocode = lookup_coords("USA",apikey = "google_maps_token"),
                n=10, include_rts = FALSE)
```

Searching for tweets...
Finished collecting tweets!

[10 tweets from USA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kayCz.png)

collect tweets from Mexico

```
tweets_Mexico <- search_tweets("#lang:es",
                           geocode = lookup_coords("mexico",apikey = "google_maps_token"),
                n=10, include_rts = FALSE)
```

Searching for tweets...
Finished collecting tweets!

[no data collected from Mexico](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tftnC.png)

Also, when I use the lookup_coords() function from rtweet package with "usa" it works

get coordinates from USA

```
usa <- lookup_coords("usa")
```

[coordinates from USA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kUjJi.png)

but when I try to use another address following the examples in the help section it does not collect any data

get coordinates from Brazil

```
bz <- lookup_coords("brazil")
```

[no coordinates from Brazil](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0OjKJ.png)

But when I directly write the API key in the function it works.
For security reasons I write instead "XXXXXXXXXX"

```
mexico_coord <- lookup_coords(address = "mexico",
                          components = "country:Mexico",
                          apikey = "XXXXXXXXXXXX")
```

[mexico coordinates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6JEfe.png)

Am I doing something wrong or do I need to install the API key in another directory? I have to say that my working directory (where I save my projects and scripts) is different from the home directory that appears as a result of running  path.expand("~/")

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution to get the lookup_coords() function to work properly.
I simply have to use the Sys.getenv() function to call the google_maps_token.rds

generate a variable with the coordinates from Mexico

```
mexico_coord <- lookup_coords(address = "mexico",
                          components = "country:Mexico",
                          apikey=Sys.getenv("google_maps_token.rds"))
```

Afterwards I can use the search_tweet() function to collect 10 tweets from Mexico in spanish

```
tuits_Mex_esp_10 <- search_tweets("lang:es",
                          geocode = mexico_coord, n = 10)
```